# binance-python: How to get futures symbol data?

Tags: python, binance

I see a function in client.py called `futures_exchange_info(self)`. What is `self` here? The documentation is really slim but I'm assuming it refers to [Exchange Information](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#exchange-information)? How does this function work exactly? I've tried calling it as `futures_exchange_info('VETUSDT')` but I just get the error: "TypeError: futures_exchange_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".

Does anyone know how this function works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the word 'self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `Client` object and then call `client.futures_exchange_info()`. The method takes no parameters and according to the documentation returns "Current exchange trading rules and symbol information".

Something like this should work:

```
from binance.client import Client

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
info = client.futures_exchange_info()
```

Documentation is [here](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) and take a look at the [quick start](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#quick-start).

Comment: There we go! Thank you! Not quite as elegant of an output as `client.get_symbol_info` but you work with what's available I guess.

Comment: For um_futures: [exchange_info()](https://github.com/binance/binance-futures-connector-python/blob/main/binance/um_futures/market.py#L35)